# Product ID for in app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios

My app id is like com.MyApp-01. I have to use in app purchase in my app.What product id should i create on iTunes. As per apple rules i need to create product id like com.MyApp-01.productID for testing but i can't add  this symbol '-'in product id .

Comment: Is 01 a part of your game name? Or it means something like version? You may set `com.MyApp.productID` or replace/strip `-` symbol. These rules are made to standardize naming for comfort. I have met ID's like `productID.com.mycompany.appname` in live Appstore apps.

Comment: my app id is like com.MyApp-01 ad it is currently on app store and -01 is there at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product ID doesn't *have* to start with your bundle ID. You can simply drop the dash and use com.MyApp.productID, or even just productID.

Comment: i had tried like that and tested in app purchase but it gives me error of invalid product id

Comment: are you sure you're requesting the correct product id from your app?

Comment: i created productid somehwat like this com.MyCompanyname.MYappname but then also i get invalid product id what can be the reason.